# How to use C# dll in UWP

Tags: c#, dll, uwp

I have a C# dll compiled in .net framework 2.0 and the library is not been updated by the vendor till now. In one of my desktop application C# i was using that and when i migrated the application to WPF, the same libraries where referred and working fine. Now, the application required new diversion, as it should be upgraded to UWP and the same dll i want to make use in that also. What is the best and easiest methods available in UWP to import.Net Framework 2.0 dll ?

Regards,
Lal

Comment: Since it is not clear what you're exactly having problem with, I suggest you to google "c# import dll" that should lead you somewhere.

Comment: A UWP app targets .NETCore, so this library is not usable.  You could consider the desktop bridge as an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best and easiest methods available in UWP to import.Net Framework 2.0 dll ?

You can not direct consume any  full  .NET Class Library from UWP app, there is some security restrictions. UWP project can reference libraries such as Universal Windows Class Library,[.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) library, [Windows Runtime Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/) and so on.

For solving this, since your app is for desktop devices and you already have a WPF app, I recommend you to convert the WPF app to UWP app by using [Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root).  Or you could try to convert the old dll into one of above the libraries that can be referenced by UWP app. If you do only want to consume the .Net framework dll, you may try to create COM Proxy Stubs and work with them as communication layer, [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ProxyStubsForWinRTComponents) is the official sample.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a **.NET Standard 2.0 library project** that can reference the legacy library and you can then reference this .NET Standard 2.0 project from you UWP app.

In the .NET Standard library, you can write custom types that access the legacy library and provide a "middleware layer" between the UWP app and the legacy library.

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this is to make a windows service and use that dll in service. You can reference that service from UWP application in order to make all the API calls.